# zsh: How to test for existence of two programs on zsh use $+commands

Tags: zsh

In zsh we can test for the existence of a progragram using this:

```
(( $+commands[program] )) && program
```

My question is: How to use `commands` for testing the existence of two programs instead one?

Answer (score 5):

Found this under `Subscript Flags` in `man 1 zshparam` (portions removed, emphasis added):

> `r` if  this  flag  is  given,  the `exp` is taken as a pattern

> `i` Like `r`,

> `I` Like `i`, but gives the index of the last match, **or all possible matching keys in an associative array.** On failure substitutes 0, or the empty string for an associative array. **This flag is best when testing for values or keys that do not exist.**

So to test for both `program1` and `program2`, you can do:

```
(( $#commands[(I)(program1|program2)] == 2 ))
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could just use the following:

```
if ((( $+commands[program1] ) && ( $+commands[program2] ))); then
  echo 'both command exists'
fi
```

the same could be done using bash:

```
if [[ `command -v program1` && `command -v program2`]]; then
  echo 'both command exists'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a little bit similar with what I did in my ouw answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out one way of solving this issue:

```
alias rm='echo use trash instead!'
(( $+commands[trash] && $+commands[gio] )) && alias trash='gio trash'
```

I still would like to know if it is possible to use something like:

```
(( $+commands[program1 program2] ))
```

Comment: By the way: The `gio` is a gnome-shell library, more about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_(software)